# can't launch ZENDx for a specific view

Tags: php, jquery-ui, zend-framework, zend-form

I'm trying to enable and start using ZENDx in my application.

I've gone through tons of link through google but still it remains obscure.

I want to launch and use JQuery in specific views only. for ex. when I want to use auto-complete or datepicker of jQuery UI.

I started with http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.8/en/zendx.jquery.view.html

First I added ZendX to my library.
Then followed the manual - that didn't work at all.

I added this code: `$view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");`  to my controller, right before passing my $form.

then added `<?php $this->jQuery(); ?>` into my Head Tag.

then, for testing purposes I pasted the code given in the manual into my view:

```
<?php echo $this->ajaxLink("Show me something", "/hello/world", array('update' => '#content')); ?>

<div id="content"></div>
<form method="post" action="/hello/world">
    Pick your Date: <?php echo $this->datePicker("dp1", '', array('defaultDate' => date('Y/m/d', time()))); ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

P.S. please mention how to call specific version of jQuery and UI or just call them locally.

There was a Bug in my code, after I published this question. This code above, works fine and it worked for me, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change your setup like the following.

Add to your **application.ini:**

```
pluginPaths.ZendX_Application_Resource  = "ZendX/Application/Resource"
```

And to your **View e.g Layout.phtml**

```
 <?php echo $this->jQuery()->enable(); ?>
```